# Auth0 in Rails with devise has nil in the request.env['omniauth.auth']

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, omniauth, auth0

I'm setting up a rails app that has Active Admin using devise and I'm trying to add an OmniAuth authentication using Auth0.

I've installed the `gem 'omniauth-auth0', '~> 2.2'`.

I've added the callback controller and routes.

I've added the middleware initializer (note that the `AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET` is null)

```
# config/initializers/auth0.rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider(
    :auth0,
    ENV.fetch('AUTH0_CLIENT_ID'),
    ENV.fetch('AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    ENV.fetch('AUTH0_DOMAIN'),
    callback_path: '/auth/auth0/callback'
  )
end
```

My devise initilizer has nothing related to OAuth.

The view has the code:

```
<div class="oauth hidden">
  <div id="root" style="width: 320px; margin: 40px auto; padding: 10px; border-style: dashed; border-width: 1px; box-sizing: border-box;">
    embedded area
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.2/lock.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var lock = new Auth0Lock(
      '<%= ENV.fetch('AUTH0_CLIENT_ID') %>',
      '<%= ENV.fetch('AUTH0_DOMAIN') %>', {
        container: 'root',
        auth: {
          redirectUrl: '<%=ENV.fetch('AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL') %>',
          responseType: 'code',
          params: {
            scope: 'openid profile email' // Learn about scopes: https://auth0.com/docs/scopes
          }
        }
      });
    lock.show();
  </script>
</div>
```

And the controller has:

```
module Api
  class Auth0Controller < ApplicationController
    def callback
      # This stores all the user information that came from Auth0
      # and the IdP
      session[:userinfo] = request.env['omniauth.auth']

      # Redirect to the URL you want after successful auth
      redirect_to admin_dashboard_url
    end

    def failure
      # show a failure page or redirect to an error page
      @error_msg = request.params['message']
    end
  end
end
```

Now, it seems like the middleware is not working as it should. The callback from the Auth0 server has a url parameter like this: `code=XXXXXXXXXXXX` and in the callback action and the value of `request.env['omniauth.auth']` is nil.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problems:

1. The routes were inside scopes, so the callback path defined in `config/initializers/auth0.rb` should account for that like: `/api/auth/auth0/callback`.
2. The `admin_user` model was omniauthable and it was overriding the routes defined for the callbacks.